# OAuth1.0a C library or HMAC-SHA1 C library

Tags: hmacsha1

I am building a cross platform desktop application in LiveCode using a Mac with targets of Mac and Windows, but can translate any responses from C/C++.

I need to interact with a web API that uses OAuth1.0a. Yes, there is Java support for OAuth1.0a, but Apple seems to be vigorously attempting to eliminate any use of Java in MacOS. So I am attempting to implement without Java.

I think I have found a way to implement most of OAuth1.0a, except for the HMACSHA1 piece to generate the oauthSignature. Translating from Java is non-trivial because there are a lot of support classes referenced.

I have seen in some posts where people reference a HMACSHA1 library, but I don't know from where. I have done a number of searches on GitHub, but I only found one there "hmac-sha1-master" that was complete and it delivers a different answer than Java's implementation.

Anybody know of an up to date implementation of HMACSHA1 in C/C++ or a Java that does not descend deep into supporting Java libraries?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Googling "HMAC SHA1 C++" has several results. If none of them are enough, please be more specific with your expectations. Otherwise, I have personally used CryptoPP and it has a sane API.

Comment: I have a public domain sha1 library for LiveCode (not by me). I have made a minimal change andI think I could post the code here as an answer. Could you post an example of your input string and tell me what output string you'd expect? I'd like to check if this library may to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found parts of the answer to this. Following is the header from a LiveCode library that handles SHA1, several SHA2 versions, HMAC and combinations of HMAC and SHA. The link to download the library from is included.

/*
libHash-Hmac
version 2.3
Version 2.3 Mark Smith, mark@maseurope.net
9th September 2009
http://marksmith.on-rev.com/revstuff/
v2.3 added crc 16, 16ccitt, 32 functions
v2.2 added htpasswd sha1 functions
v2.1 optimised sha256 processing by putting rotations in line.
Includes hmacSha1
*/

Still need to do work to finish off an OAuth1.0. But this library handles the most intensive part of the coding.